# How to prevent SIGBREAK from terminating Ubuntu app in Windows 10?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using the Ubuntu app inside of Windows 10 (Dell XPS 13). To my surprise, typing Ctrl-Fn-B instantly kills the Ubuntu app. So does Ctrl-Fn-S.

These key combinations do not have this effect on other applications. As you can imagine, a key combination that terminates the application without saving work is a bit terrifying.

I'd like to understand *why* these keys have this effect, and additionally, how to prevent this effect.

===

Editing to add what I've learned:

On my keyboard, Fn-B is Break, so Ctrl-Fn-B is Ctrl-Break, i.e. SIGBREAK. I'm assuming but can't quite verify that Fn-S is something similar, possibly Scroll Lock.

So now I have an explanation for why the behavior occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> are break keys. In modern keyboards, there is no separate <kbd>Break</kbd> key and the above said keys are the alternatives for that.

It also depends on the application that whether it recognizes those keystrokes or not. For example, when Windows Powershell application is used, it don't recognize that but when it is used in [Windows Terminal](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-terminal-preview/9n0dx20hk701), it recognizes it as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

On the other hand, command prompt just terminates the process ongoing. Since Ubuntu app on Windows uses command prompt as its front-end, thus when those key combinations are used, "ubuntu" gets terminated and the app closes. You can verify this thing if you run `ubuntu` on CMD and then use one of those key combinations. You'll observe that `ubuntu` is terminated and you're back to command prompt.

#### Further Reading:

- [Break key - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Break_key)
- [break key alternative - Dell Community](https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General-Read-Only/break-key-alternative/td-p/3826467)